# Does frequency determine the directionality of waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, waves

While reading some introductory material on electromagnetic waves I stumbled upon the following statement.

> Higher frequency waves are more directional

Does this mean that the waves in the, for example, ultra violet bands of the electromagnetic spectrum travel as narrow beams, whereas the radio waves propagate omni-directionally.

Side questions, 1) what is the role of propagation mechanisms (diffraction and scattering) in this, and 2) what is the role of antenna design?

Although related to Acoustics this questions implies something similar: [Directionality of sound depending on emitter size and wavelength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307527/directionality-of-sound-depending-on-emitter-size-and-wavelength)

Comment: That statement is rather bold and not  really accurate.  One can definitely generate an omnidirectional x-ray source (e.g., thermal Bremsstrahlung radiation on the sun is not collimated or beamed).

Comment: under what conditions would this statement be correct? if we consider diffraction. I noticed multiple articles giving the example of music bands and why the high pitch sounds are heard first from distance... would the same apply to EM?

Answer (score 3):

The highlighted statement is false.  Probably what the writer means is that for a fixed size antenna or emitter, the lower the frequency the more point-like the source.  But it is practical to produce single mode gaussian beams of a given divergence (i.e., directional) for any EM frequency between microwaves and x-rays.  There are always going to be limitations due to wavelength a (how big an antenna or emitter can you build) or material properties for lenses (it's hard to find materials that have decent index and low loss at 1 Thz), but these have nothing to do with the properties of waves.  A wave is a wave.  You can also use phased arrays to produce diffraction limited beams at lower frequency at the cost of using lots of small elements.   The details of antenna design depend on the wavelength primarily for technological reasons.  For for frequencies from microwave to THz, Goldsmith's Quasioptical systems is good source.  For RF, the ARRL antenna handbook is nice.  Any good optics book will cover that part of the spectrum.   There are books on phased arrays, nano-antennas, x-ray optics, etc.  It's much too broad to cover all the technology.  But the fundamental wave issues scale with frequency and emitter size.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly author had in mind, but I highly suspect it must be thinking about [diffraction limited system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system), where waves scattering angle around diffracting object depends inversely on wave frequency :
$$ \theta = \sin^{-1} \frac {\lambda}{2nd} \tag 1$$
where $d$ scattering object diameter. So higher frequency waves has lower wavelength, which gives smaller diffraction angles $\theta$, and hence - more wave-packet energy will go unscattered or scattered with low angles than compared to low frequency waves.

Answer (score 0):

This kinds of statements are conventionally made about radio waves, whose wave lengths range from $1$mm ($300$GHz - short wave length, high frequency) to $10000$km ($300$Hz - long wave length, low frequency). What is meant in this case is that long waves may go around objects (due to refraction) or may propagate between objects (or even in the layer of atmosphere) as within a waveguide, essentially following the form of the corridor (e.g., some radio waves are known to travel around the earth.)

On the other hand, short radio waves are perceived a directional, since an obstacle blocking the straight line between the transmitter and the receiver blocks the transmission (*line-of-sight propagation*.) They also can be made literally directed by using a reflector of appropriate shape.

Of course, the statement becomes pretty meaningless when made out of this context: either about electromagnetic waves in general or in the conditions other than those where we typically sue the radio waves.

Wikipedia gives a rather good discussion, see:
[Radio wave: propagation characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_wave#Propagation_characteristics) and [Radio propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation), discussing *line-of-sight propagation*, *indirect propagation*, *ground waves* and *sky waves*